# How to get Units in the CloudWatch metrics ingested via the amazon-cloudwatch-agent collectd socket listener?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have the amazon-cloudwatch-agent configured to [retrieve custom metrics via collectd](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-custom-metrics-collectd.html).

That is working in the sense that I can see the metrics in CloudWatch UI, but they have no **unit** (for example the `collectd_GenericJMX_java_heap_used` should have `Bytes` as CloudWatch Unit).

As far as I know collectd does **not** have the concept of units, and it seems that neither does `telegraf.Metric` (which I think is the underlying concept that is used in the amazon-cloudwatch-agent to ingest collectd metrics).

Is there any way, to specify the "units" for collectd metrics?